# About staging tables and merge

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence, staging

I'm really new in the BI world, and some concepts seems misunderstood for me.

I'm reading some articles and books about this, they are full of graphics and flows that does not tell much about the process in practice.

About the staging tables and the extraction process.

**I know that the tables in staging area need to be deleted after the flow has been executed.**

Considering this, imagine a flow with a initial full extraction to the target database. Then, using a merge cdc, i need to identify what was updated in the source tables. My doubt is here, how can i know what was updated since my tables are on the target, and the data on staging has been deleted?

I need to bring the data of the target tables to the staging area and then do the merge?

Comment: Does [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/07/09/ssis-design-pattern-incremental-loads.aspx) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Data Capture (CDC) is usually done on the source system, either with an explicit `changed` field (either a simple boolean or a timestamp) or automatically by the underlying database management system.

If you have a timestamp field in your data you first do your initial load to staging, record the maximum timestamp retrieved, and then on the next update you only retrieve records where the timestamp is greater than your recorded value. This is the preferred way to do it if there's no real CDC functionality on the source system.

Using a boolean field is trickier as all inserts and updates to the source-system must set it to `true` and after your extraction you'll have to reset it to `false`.

Comment: First, thanks for your fast reply. So, in fact, on my staging area i need a table with the data previosly pulled, to compare the data with the new coming from the source? I though i need to clean all of my data on the staging.. Or, as i said, i need to put on the staging, the data that i have on target, to do this comparison?

Comment: Yes, you can have some bookkeeping and configuration data on staging but it's a good practice to clean out all the tables that you have loaded from source. You don't need to have all the data in staging just the highest timestamp you have retrieved from source. And you don't need to do that for all of your data, just the biggest tables like facts.